# Conversion of jar to dll using ikvm

Tags: dll, jar, ikvm

I am trying to convert a jar into dll in dotnet using IKVM but am getting this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: \Location of the jar\...

CAn anyone provide some guidance..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 21):

Prerequisites -

1. You must have the JDK installed on your system.
2. Set the environment variables for the JDK.

[image]

Steps:

1. Open the command prompt.
2. Go to the `ikvmc` folder (`ikvmc.exe` comes with the `ikvm` package).
3. Enter the command `ikvmc -out:myapp.dll myapp.jar`

Comment: I get lot of `class not found` errors although all the related/referenced jars reside in same directory

Comment: The JAR Files which is to be converted to DLL should be complied with JAVA JDK 1.7 or below. This limitation is because IKVM currently does not support converting JAR files compiled with JDK 1.8 or above.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a new Bindings Library project. In Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio, create a new Solution and select the Android Bindings Library template.

The template includes a Jars folder where you add your .JAR(s) to the Bindings Library project. Right-click the Jars folder and select Add > Existing Item:

Navigate to the .jar file downloaded earlier, select it and click Add:

Verify that the .jar file was successfully added to the project:

right click your jar file=>properities =>choose embedded jar

Set the build action to EmbeddedJar:

EmbeddedJar – the .JAR will be embedded in the Bindings Library.

Set the target API level for your Bindings Library

Finally, build the Bindings Library. Although some warning messages may be displayed, the Bindings Library project should build successfully and produce an output .DLL at the following location:

Projectname/bin/Debug/JarBinding.dll

Reference

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/

Comment: He's asking to convert to a dll. Not to import a jar.

Comment: Actually, if you read the full comment, this answer is wrapping a JAR in a DLL using Xamarin. This is a clever approach, although I don't know how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you forgot reference all needed IKVM .Net dlls?

IKVM.Runtime.dll
IKVM.Reflection.dll
IKVM.OpenJDK.*.dll

I've got something similar with SmsLib .Net version

Answer (score 0):

The follow wiki pages should be helpful:

- http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=ClassLoader
- http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Ikvmc
- http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Ikvmc_messages