# Is there any possibility to use JAR Files in .NET?

Tags: java, c#, .net, jar

## Initial situation

First of all, I want explain the initial situation of my problem. I'm aware of the **non-existing interoperability** between Java and .NET. I've done a lot of research about this topic already, but couldn't find a suitable solution yet. Anyways I am convinced that there is a solution!

I'm creating a C# library that needs access to `.jar` files or more precisely it needs access to Java classes. The use of Java classes in C# is very important, since I need to pass in parameters and wait for a result.

## Example

The following is a very simplified example of how it should ideally work. Note that deviations are welcome, since they can't be excluded in the final solution. The only important thing is that I can create a class instance of the Java class in C#.

**calculation.java:**

```java
public class Calculation
{
    public int Add(Integer a, Integer b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    public int Subtract(Integer a, Integer b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
}
```

**entrypoint.cs:**

```cs
// Implement / load the Java file
// like: using calculation;

public class Foo
{
    public string Bar()
    {
        // The original constructor of the class is of course in Java
        Calculation calc = new Calculation(); // Create class instance
        int res = calc.Add(5, 10); // Call method
    }
}
```

## Progress

First of all I tried to integrate / load the `.jar` files into Visual Studio / C# directly, but I couldn't find a way to do something like that.

Futhermore I tried to use [IKVM8](https://github.com/windward-studios/ikvm8) to convert my `.jar` files into `.dll` files (**D**ynamic **L**ink **L**ibrary), but the open-source project isn't maintained anymore & I get weird errors along the way.

Another possible solution is to use JavaScript to create the class instances and to implement JavaScript into C#, but I think this is a very unclean way if it is possible at all.

Currently I am trying to convert the `.jar` files into `.dll` files again via [Jni4net](https://github.com/jni4net/jni4net). However, I couldn't figure out how to use it in order to translate the `.jar` files into `.dll` files.

I highly appreciate any suggestions, sheers!

Comment: Here someone is suggesting wrapping the jar in a xamarin dll:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40802639/14865005

Comment: @T.Schwarz Thanks a lot! I've already came accross with that, but I wasn't sure if I could produce a .dll of the whole C# project at the end. Maybe you know more about that?

Comment: If you can run a JVM on the side, you would need to be able to ask it "instantiate and run this, send me the result". Which should be doable as a REST service using reflection. Or some other remote call mechanism. Is corba still a thing?

Comment: @dratenik Wow, actually a very nice idea! I thought about a REST service once for the C# project, but never thought about building  REST for the Java things itself. Indeed a very good idea & propably more approachable than my idea

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at JNI (Java Native Interface), with it you can instantiate a Java VM from C# and instantiate and call Java classes.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much! :) As I said I tried to use jni4net, but couldn't figure out how to translate my .jar files with it. Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: Ah the 'convert' bit got me, using JNI you don't convert the JARs, you use them as is. I see JNI4net does have some convenient c# proxy generation tools, which handle the details of argument type conversion.